# Fetching API returns object

Tags: arrays, reactjs, fetch

I'm trying to fetch http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gettoptracks&api_key=a3c9fd095f275f4139c33345e78741ed&format=json , and I must to show top tracks, but when I'm trying to map it , or find array to map there is no way:

```
// imports
export default class HomePage extends Component {
    state = {
        result: {}
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`
        http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gettoptracks&api_key=a3c9fd095f275f4139c33345e78741ed&format=json
        `)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(result => this.setState({ result }))
            
    }
    renderItems(arr) {
        return arr.map((item) => {
            return (
                <div className="top-line">{item.name}
                </div>
            )
        })
    }
    render() {
        
        const { result } = this.state;
        console.log(result)
        const { hints = [] } = result;
        console.log(hints)
        const items = this.renderItems(hints);
        return(
            <ul className="item-list list-group">
                {items}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your code, so it will be helpful

Comment: I think you you must run through the response and write your own toplist parser

Comment: @StimpsonCat I have tried many different ways

Comment: @s662720h_uu Added the answer with functional component, let me know it it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find `hints` property from your snippet. Also i have rewritten your code using functional component kindly check

**Note**: For blocked content issue, added the meta tag in `index.html`, this may not come on from project setup. In codesandbox it was required so added to show the working snippet.

**index.html**

```
  <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="upgrade-insecure-requests"
    />
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [topSongs, setTopSongs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gettoptracks&api_key=a3c9fd095f275f4139c33345e78741ed&format=json"
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setTopSongs(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {topSongs?.tracks?.track.length &&
        topSongs.tracks.track.map((datumn) => {
          return (
            <Fragment key={datumn.name}>
              <div>{datumn.name}</div>
              <hr />
            </Fragment>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-dirac-2w7ty)

I hope this will give you a better understanding

Comment: Thanks for your time, is there documentation I should to read?

Comment: Welcome, happy to help, Please vote if it really helped you :) ,You can read the official one, https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html. Happy coding :)